# How to modify a List value while debugging in IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-14, android-studio-2.0

I need to change a variable during debugging an application. Until now it was just basic variables which could directly be set. Now I need to clear an array so that `isEmpty()` returns true;

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>;
someList.add("1");
...
if(someList.isEmpty()){ //break point
//need to enter here
}
```

In the intellij debugger I see:

```
someList={ArrayList@4271} size=1
```

I used the 'setValue' method of the debugger and tried: `new ArrayList<String>()` or `someList = new ArrayList<String>()`

which results in

```
someList={ArrayList@4339} size=0
```

However if I continue I get a NullPointerException when the isEmpty() is called. So my question: **How can I inject an empty ArrayList without getting a NPE?**

The text of the NPe is: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.isEmpty()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Did you try to use the "Evaluate expression" during debug ("<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>" on Windows) ?

In this window you can write :

```
 someList.clear();
```

or

```
someList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And it should do the trick.

Comment: Oh Man, I was searching for this everywhere, finally found it thanks a lot for answering :)

Comment: Doesn't work with Kotlin: `Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context`

Comment: I had to clear the list and someList.clear(); worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Stop the breakpoint at `if(someList.isEmpty())`, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> (evaluate expression), type `someList.clear()`, press `Evaluate` and just proceed on debugging. Now it will definitly enter the if condition.

Comment: thanks, yeah that did the trick - your answer is correct. Guillaume was a bit faster so I accepted his answer - can't accept both ;-)

Comment: No problem. Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue, but I am using Kotlin, 
which you can do `(someList as ArrayList<*>).clear()`